# What are these odd bumps on my Dachshund's cheeks?

Tags: dogs, skin-condition, dachshunds, anatomy

Our Dachshund puppy has started to grow three odd bumps: one on each cheek and a smaller one on the underside of her chin.

Please examine this photo taken just a moment ago:

[image]

I have circled the bump in red. It has two hair strands growing out of it.  The symmetrical one on her right cheek also has two hair strands growing out of it, and the less pronounced bump under her chin has about 5 hair strands growing out of it.

What problem, if any, do these odd bumps (or moles?) indicate?  Or alternatively, should we approach the vet to have them removed?

Comment: Seems normal to me, based some other pictures of similar, but we do have an avid dachshund person, so I summon @JoshDM. As an aside, if you do find unusual lumps, it _never_ hurts to take your pup to see a vet.

Comment: They're just little whisker lumps, nothing to be concerned about; all older dachshunds I've seen have them (including my own).

Comment: My dog has them too accept the one under his chin seems to be getting bigger. Any ideas what it could be? Looks like a white pimple to me.

Comment: ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9gyT.jpg) My dog has the same 2 on his right cheek and 1 on his left cheek

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, don't worry. Those "bumps" are completely normal. All dogs got them, it just depends a bit on the race how well you can see them. They're very noticeable on our Husky for example.

As you've noticed and others mentioned, they are the areas where the whiskers originate.

Just check those three spots occasionally, as there might sit ticks right next to them, which would be harder to spot compared to other body parts.

Answer (score 5):

They're called "vibrissae"-- they're not defects, they serve an important function. They're sensitive receptors, like a cat's whiskers. They pick up air currents and alert a dog to any movement or change in their immediate surroundings.

Answer (score -3):

It’s 100% normal my dog has it too. It’s just like when a human has a mole it normal just check and look up close because they could or could not be a tick right next it them and the round figure with hair growing out could also be a part of tissue with extra skin